# FSharp FAKE - Tracing Process Output

Tags: f#, f#-fake

I have a FAKE task where I am calling Visual Studio to build a setup project. I have been playing around with ExecProcess and ExecProcessRedirected, but am unable to get tracing to work. In other words, I want to log all of the build output messages from VS as it runs.

Comment: Why are you using VS to build? Why not MSBuild?

Comment: As stated, it's a VS setup project. You can't build those with MSBuild.

Comment: ExecProcess is only capturing the stdout - I'm not sure if VS is tracing to this.

Answer (score 3):

My honest opinion is: don't use VS during a build. You'll end up installing VS on CI servers and everything will become worse. Try to find a different way. You can use [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) which has already a [FAKE task](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-wixhelper.html) or other installer tools which don't require VS.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not an option

Comment: I'm curious: why not?